Send istream over HTTP using WinInet
I have an istream which length is not known that I want to send to an HTTP server.
I have to use the windows API in wininet.h.
I already a code that works but it requires the total size of the istream.
So is there a way to do the same thing when the total size is unknown ?
By the way, the total size may be larger than 4Gb !
Here is a minimalist (errors not checked) version of my code :
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>

using namespace std ;

void UploadSomeData ( string server , int port , istream & input , size_t totalsize )
    {
    string    agt = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1" ;
    HINTERNET ses = InternetOpenA( agt.c_str(), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET con = InternetConnectA( ses,server.c_str(),port,NULL,NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,0,0);
    HINTERNET req = HttpOpenRequestA( con,"POST","/upload", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);

    HttpAddRequestHeaders( req,"Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n",-1,HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE | HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD) ;

    INTERNET_BUFFERSA buffers = { 0 };
    buffers.dwStructSize  = sizeof( buffers ) ;
    buffers.dwBufferTotal = DWORD( totalsize ) ;
    HttpSendRequestExA(req, &buffers, NULL, HSR_INITIATE, 0) ;

    for (;;)
        {
        const int chunk_size = 10000 ;
        char chunk [chunk_size] ;
        input.read( chunk,chunk_size ) ;
        int count = int( input.gcount()) ;
        if (count == 0) break ;
        DWORD written ;
        InternetWriteFile( req,chunk,count,&written ) ;
        }

    HttpEndRequest(req, NULL, 0, 0) ;
    InternetCloseHandle( req ) ;
    InternetCloseHandle( con ) ;
    InternetCloseHandle( ses ) ;
    }

int main ()
    {
    string s = "spam and eggs." ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++ ) s = s+s ; // produce a big string (14M chars)
    istringstream i ( s ) ;
    UploadSomeData( "127.0.0.1",3456,i,s.length()) ;
    return 0;
    }

I have read somewhere, that the second argument of HttpSendRequestEx may be NULL but it doesn't work...
Thanks !

https://stackoverflow.com/q/10050153/179634

Chunked transfer encoding requires the client to send the length of each chunk, before the chunk itself.  See an example here. I'm pretty sure you'd have to write that yourself, WinInet won't do this for you. InternetWriteFile just sends the bytes as-is.

You would also need to send a 0-length chunk after you are done sending the other chunks. But this is moot, because apparently WinInet does not support chunked uploads, you have to use WinHTTP instead.
